# Error de zona horaria con JDBC MYSQLCONECTOR java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

estoy tratando de hacer la conexion a mysql con conector jdbc en java jsp pero me da el siguiente error:  java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Lo solucione con la linea SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00'; en mysql, pero al reiniciar mysql en xampp vuelve al mismo error y tendria que ejecutar el set global cada vez que inicio mysql y no me parece muy correcto, no se de que otra manera puedo realizar esto.
Lo hice con la linea jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC en la cadena de conexion pero sigue sin servir o nose como debo agregar mi cadena de conexion con la anterior mi conexion es:

```
  public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?user=root&password=");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion en wc get " + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo fue [reportado como un bug en el año 2019](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95036), es un error conocido de JDBC 8.

Varias soluciones son posibles:

### 1. Pasar el timezone en la cadenas de conexión

```
  public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion en wc get " + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

### 2. Cambiar la configuración global en MySQL

Eso lo puedes hacer editando el archivo `my.cnf` o `my.ini` según el caso ([ver punto 1 de este artículo](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/java-sql-sqlexception-the-server-time-zone-value-xx-time-is-unrecognized/)).

---

### *Enlaces*

Para más detalles puedes ver:

- Indicaciones sobre timezone en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/8.0/en/mem-localization.html).
- Indicaciones propias sobre cómo funciona [JDBC 8 en el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-other-changes.html)
- Discusión sobre este problema en la [página de reporte de bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85816) de Mysql.

---

#### Aviso de código obsoleto

> **NÓTESE** que he quitado `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` porque [ha sido declarado obsoleto a partir de JDBC 4](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/obsolete/RSPEC-4925).

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio aunque tengo un problema muy raro y minimo pero sirve jajaja, quite el ClassforName y arranque el proyecto y no funciono sigue con el mismo error pero le di atras en el navegador puse correo y clave nuevamente en el login y de hay en adelante empieza a servir normal, es raro no funciona en la primera pero de la segunda en adelante si, ya limpie y construi pero sigue igual falla a la primera pero a la segunda no.

Comment: @Angelita en la cadena de conexión `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", ""` he puesto la clave en blanco, porque en tu código no aparecía clave. Prueba a poner la clave en el último parámetro, donde aparecen las comillas solas, después de `root`

Comment: Cedeno si así la deje  " conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");  " , mira que a la primera no funciona pero despues si, el error que bota de primera es ->  No se encontró un controlador adecuado para jdbc: mysql: // localhost / ventas? ServerTimezone = UTC <-- y cuando pongo la classforName sirve a la primera pero me da este mensaje -->  La nueva clase de controlador es `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver '. El controlador se registra automáticamente a través del SPI y la carga manual de la clase de controlador generalmente no es necesaria

Comment: Es raro, porque `Class.forName` dice que ya no es necesario. Puede que sea un problema de configuración o de versión de MySQL, por lo que no encuentra el controlador y entonces necesites usar `Class.forName` ¿?

Comment: Si consulte y es obsoleto, incluso la consola de netbeans lo dice  y funciona en el segundo intento del login, pero en la primera ejecución siempre falla pero de resto bien es super raro.

Comment: @Angelita pero, ¿le estás pasando el password  en parámetro o no?

Comment: si la clave la puse en blanco asi "" ya que yo no le tengo clave.

Comment: ¿Por qué en blanco, porque se loguea sin clave?

Comment: No, La clave esta en blanco en la cadena de conexion. asi.
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wooclic?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");