# Problemas con java y mySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, excepciones, framework

tengo un problema, cuando intento ejecutar un framework hecho en NetBeans versión 17 todo corre bien, mi único problema es cuando intento usar mySQL que encuentro errores en una parte en especifico.

```java
    public HypixelSkyblock() {
        initComponents();
        Connect();
    }

    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    
    public void Connect(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); //register mysql Driver
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hypixelskyblock","root","123456"); // acces the dataBase from phpMySQL
            System.out.println("MySQL connection sucsesfully");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HypixelSkyblock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //SaveActionPerform 
        try {
            String valueMoney, valueName;
        
            valueName = nameValue.getText();
            valueMoney = moneyValue.getText();
        
            pst = con.prepareStatement("Insert into record (valueName, valueMoney) values (?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, valueName);
            pst.setString(2, valueMoney);
            
            pst.executeUpdate();
            
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Save");
            
            nameValue.setText("");
            moneyValue.setText("");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HypixelSkyblock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Mi principal problema es cuando hago uso de `pst.executeUpdate();`
me marca el siguiente error:

```
run:
MySQL connection sucsesfully
Feb 26, 2023 8:52:19 PM hypixelskyblockv2.HypixelSkyblock jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hypixelskyblock.record' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    (...)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 7 seconds)
```

**¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: La tabla `hypixelskyblock.record` no existe...

Comment: Si note eso @HéctorM. Pero no encontré a que se refería ya que no se menciona en ningún lado.

Comment: ¿Notaste además que ese es el origen del problema que expones en tu pregunta?

Comment: @HéctorM. Si note que ese era el problema, pero aparentemente cuando quito '''pst.executeUpdate(); ''' de mi código no marca ni 1 error, como es lo único que de verdad esta afectando a mi código no entiendo lo que esta pasando.

Comment: @sergioluna El error dice que a tabla `record` no existe, si al eliminar "pst.executeUpdate()" no te marca ningún error es porqué nunca se ejecuta la consulta INSERT en la tabla `record` que no existe. Es decir, si nunca ejecutas la consulta nunca te saltará el error.

Comment: Lo que tienes que revisar es el nombre de la tabla que estas utilizando en la consulta, o revisar si en la base de datos `hypixelskyblock` existe una tabla llamada `record`.

Comment: Ya lo solucione @JFrame , gracias a los dos, medio sabia que tenia que hacer pero en vez de utilizar una tabla llamada "record" estaba utilizando una tabla llamada objetos, medio sabia que era eso pero no supe hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: El  mensaje de error es inequívoco: `Table 'hypixelskyblock.record' doesn't exist` indica **que la tabla `record` no existe en la base de datos `hypixelskyblock`**, el mensaje de error no habla en ninguna parte de *una tabla llamada `objetos`*. Por otra parte, si usas JDBC 4 para interactuar con la base de datos, debes saber que a partir de esa versión de JDBC `Class.forName` fue declarado obsoleto. Puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/373842/29967) para un código de conexión que no usa `Class.forName` y el enlace a la doc que habla de la obsolescencia de la misma.